# Encoding problems when importing sql statement from file

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8

I have encountered a problem, when i try to execute a sql statement I have stored in a file. The problem is that special characters like æøå becomes gibberish when they are imported to the database.

I use the code below:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host='.DBHOST.';dbname='.DBBASE;
$db = new PDO($dsn, DBUSER, DBPASS);
//$db->exec("set names 'utf8'");

$sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE wtm_meta_language";
$db->exec($sql);

$sql = file_get_contents('language.sql');

$db->exec($sql);
```

The language.sql file is encoded in UTF-8 and so is the database.
I have tried to force the database connection to use utf-8 by adding "set names 'utf8'" to my code (row 3, that is now a comment), but when I add this row nothing gets imported at all.

I hope someone has an idea to how to solve this.

Comment: It very much sounds like the input file is *not* UTF8. Can you describe how you established that the file actually *is* UTF8?

Comment: I use Netbeans as editor for my project, and has stated that all files should be UTF8. I have now opened the file in Notepad++ and here it says that the encoding is "UTF-8 w/o BOM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results are not getting retrieved because you did not add charset=utf8 .

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';dbname='.DBBASE.';charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
```

and then it should allow you to get the required result.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out when i come home from work, and then I will report back.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that PHP does not detect that the file is UTF-8 since, according to your comment, the BOM is missing.
I found this little function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#104746) which should force it to read UTF-8.

```
function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) { 
  $opts = array( 
    'http' => array( 
      'method'=>"GET", 
      'header'=>"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" 
    ) 
  ); 
  $context = stream_context_create($opts); 
  $result = @file_get_contents($fn,false,$context); 
  return $result; 
}
```

Also, if I were you I'd use [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) to set the character set on the mysql connection. Also I'd use `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';` so see what the current connection character set is.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out when i come home from work, and then I will report back.